Blazor Razor Page Reloads after Initial Load Causing Issues
For context
App : Blazor Interactive Web App
<HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveAuto" />
<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveAuto" />

builder.Services.AddSingleton<StateManagementService>();

Here's the component
@inject CharacterAPIClient CharacterAPIClient
@inject GameAPIClient GameAPIClient
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject StateManagementService StateManagementService

@page "/character/create"

@layout BlankLayout

<div>
    <h4 style="color:white;">Create a Character</h4>

    @if (StateManagementService.Games is null)
    {
        <LoadingSpinner />
    }
    else
    {
       <p>@StateManagementService.Game.First().Title;</p>
    }
</div>

@code {
    public Character NewCharacter { get; set; } = new Character();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            if (StateManagementService.Games is null)
                StateManagementService.Games = await GameAPIClient.GetAllGames();

            StateHasChanged();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error fetching games: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    public async Task CreateCharacter()
    {
        var response = await CharacterAPIClient.CreateCharacter(NewCharacter);

        if (response){
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("social");
        } 
        else
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Error creating character");
        }
    }
}

Every time I navigate to the page, either typing in the url or navigation via within the app, the page initially loads and does the OnInitializedAsync method, succesfully retrieves the List of Games.
and then it immediately reloads the page the StateManagementService.Games is null again and then I get the exception System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Failed to fetch
Even more confusing... When I hit reload on the page, I briefly see the game title and then it reloads and repeats the behavior getting stuck on the LoadingSpinner component.

I don't think you need StateHasChanged() inside your OnInitializedAsync method unless you need to manually re-render the component. Your page is firing twice because pre rendering is enabled by default. To prevent multiple trips to your API, you can use PersistentComponentState. Keep in mind since you're using InteractiveAuto, the page will be rendered either by the server or client, whichever is available first.

Fixed..... It was because I hadn't done the most basic thing to do when problem solving in Visual Studio when there's an intermittent problem occurring out of no where. All I had to do was clean the solution and rebuild it. Works fine now. I'm going to leave this post up so if someone else false for this trap, they can hopefully come across this fix.
